# Can a CMS export html files?

Tags: web-development, cms

Can I use a CMS offline, then export the relevant html files?

Comment: Can you explain some more about what you're trying to do? What do you mean by "offline?" For example, In most cases, even if the CMS isn't on a web host, you'll have to set up a web server on your local machine to even use it. And when you export the HTML, what do you plan to do with it? If you plan to upload it, various paths may not actually work on the new server, etc.

Comment: I'm trying to use MODx to design a new website, but I don't have the rights to install it on the server, however, I can upload html files, so I'm wondering if there's a way to use MODx, or another CMS for that matter, on my own laptop, design the website first and then export the html files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on response to my comment on the question, first you'd have to install the CMS on your laptop somehow. I don't know what OS you run, but you can look at MAMP for OSX or Wampserver for Windows.

At that point, you can use MODx to build out your site, etc. and when done there's a feature to [dump it out as static HTML](https://web.archive.org/web/20160415203004/http://wiki.modxcms.com/index.php/Export_static_html). (I *think* those instructions are for Evo; it's been a while. But I'd imagine the feature is still around in Revo; the demo I'm trying to access is borked at the moment.) You should then be able to upload those files to the server.

But this is a rather less than ideal process and I'd suggest resolving whatever it is that prevents you from installing software on the server itself instead, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the CMS. You'll have to look at whatever CMS you are using and see if it offers this functionality.